# ExecuteScriptAsync("document.GetElementsById('userId-input').outerHTML;;") returns null

Tags: webview2

I am able to do the following:
(in NavigationCompletedAsync handler)

````
```
string0 = ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
Regex.Unescape(string0)
string0.Remove(0, 1);
string0.Remove(string0.Length - 1, 1);
```
````

I can see the html page in an editor. The <input element with id "userId-input" is in there.

However when I do:
`ExecuteScriptAsync("document.GetElementsById('userId-input').outerHTML;");`

the result is "null"

inserting a 5 second delay between the two calls did not help.

Any inputs are appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this closed.
I has two spelling errors:
`GetElementsById`
ought to have been:
`getElementById`

It all works now.